# Context for "He never DID like her" and "He always DID like her"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, emphasis, adverb-position

I am trying to understand the usage of focused *do/does/did* that are preceded by adverbs such as *never, always, still*, etc. Are the following conversions idiomatic?

A: John liked Mary before.
B: No! John never DID like Mary!

A: John didn't always like Mary.
B: No! John always DID like Mary!

A: John doesn't like Mary anymore.
B: No! He still DOES like her!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The first one is spot on. The second would be more usual with the *did* immediately after the subject.

Let's consider *do-support* a bit more generally.

There are some constructs in English that we can only do with an auxiliary verb. For example we put "not" after it to make it negative:

> I have not got it.
>
> You are not happy.

We can't do this with other verbs, so we add a *do* and do it with that instead:

> *I ate not today.
>
> I did not eat today.
>
> *I dance not.
>
> I do not dance.

Now, we can also just use such an extra *do* to a clause in any case, in which case it adds emphasis.

> I did eat today.
>
> I do dance.

And as you note, one common reason for doing that is in response to a statement or question that had cast doubt upon what we are now affirming:

> You don't dance.
>
> I do dance!

And indeed, while generally the *do* form would be less usual, in such a context as this it's more usual.

So, in your first example you could simply refute the first statement without *did*:

> John liked Mary before.
>
> No! John never liked Mary!

But the added *did* underlines the fact that we are repudiating the previous statement, and so more natural in the context:

> John liked Mary before.
>
> No! John never did like Mary!

However, in the next two examples we have the complication of the adverb. Consider the following three sentences:

> John always liked Mary.
>
> John did always like Mary.
>
> John always did like Mary.

Here all three have the same basic meaning, but the second two apply their emphasis slightly differently as to whether they are affecting the *always* or affected by the *always*. "…did always like…" emphasises the permanence and "…always did like…" emphasises the liking.

This is a subtle enough distinction here, but consider the statement.

> John didn't always like Mary.

Because it's denying the *always* we would repudiate it with a statement that similarly affirms it:

> John did always like Mary.

Here there is a simple mirroring of the *didn't* and the *did*.

Similarly:

> John doesn't like Mary anymore.

Isn't denying "John likes Mary" as a statement that was ever true, it's denying that it remains true. And so to repudiate it we reply with a statement that emphasises that he *still* does so:

> John does still like her.

Comment: Mary's really confused about John's feelings for her now!

Comment: Thanks, this really helps, now that it's clear to me how to refute a statement with adverbs and do-support. However it's still unclear to me what _John always DID like Mary_ means. Can it be used as a refutation of some sort? Could you guys elaborate on this a bit?

Comment: Like Jon said in his answer, moving the "always" changes the emphasis in a nuanced way. "Always did like" isn't really a refutation. It's more like a confirmation that liking that person was later justified in some way, or at least that's one frequent implication.

Comment: I think I got it, William, and it conforms with what I heard before. Thanks.